# Euro currency symbol won't display, even though other symbols work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, currency

I'm sending data from one page to the next in an MVC2 app.  Page 1 sends price information, and Page 2 displays a total w/ taxes.  Using Fiddler, I can see my data being posted properly from Page 1 as such:

`itemA_3225=Description&itemB_3225=123&itemCurrency_3225=USD&itemSymbol_3225=%24`

Then, in the Post method of my Controller, I have this line:

```
mySymbol = Request.Form["itemSymbol_" + itemID].ToString();
```

and `mySymbol` gets updated properly as `"$"`.

However, when I try doing this for Euros it doesn't work, even though everything else seems similar:

`itemA_3226=Description&itemB_3226=123&itemCurrency_3226=EUR&itemSymbol_3226=%80`

But in my Controller the `mySymbol` variable gets set to `""`.  Any ideas?  $ and £ work fine, but Euros and ƒ do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `%80` in the URI for a Euro symbol. The character set for the URI is always UTF-8, so you must send the character `U+20AC`, or, uuencoded, `%E2%82%AC`

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I encode the character properly?  I've tried HttpUtility.HtmlEncode / Decode, but that still doesn't recognize Euros.

Comment: Yep, I needed a combination of UrlEncode on page A, and UrlDecode on page B.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IN my experience 90% of the time with errors like this the problem has to do with reading/writing with the wrong character set.